# Not able to installing sails.js

Tags: node.js, npm, sails.js

I have node and npm versions :

```
C:\Windows\system32>node -v
v4.5.0

C:\Windows\system32>npm -v
3.10.6
```

I tried to install sails.js as administator

```
npm install -g sails
```

In C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\
It has created a .staging file folder
and then sails folder...
but again later .staging folder got deleted automatically...
And at administator console log ended with this error...

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\sjammulamada\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\
npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "sails"
npm ERR! node v4.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.6
npm ERR! path C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\.staging\lodash-86452639
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall rename

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\.staging\lodash-86452639' ->
'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\sails\node_modules\anchor\node_modules\lodash'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\.staging\lodash-86452639' ->
'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\sails\node_modules\anchor\node_modules\lodash'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Windows\system32\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! code 1
```

I tried

```
npm cache clean
```

and then tried to install sails.js ..but still no results ... I must be missing somthing let me know..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should run command line as administrator then

```
npm cache clean
```

now you are ready to install sailsjs

```
npm install -g sails
```

if still issue then you may try

```
npm install -g sails --ignore-scripts
```